# Vue: render <script> tag inside a variable (data string)

Tags: vue.js, script-tag

I'm new to Vue.js

I want to render a script tag inside a variable (data string).

I tried to us a v-html directive to do so, but it doesn't work Nothing is rendered

Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I dont fully understand your question.  Do you mean you have a string variable that contains html/javascript that you want to render inside another html tag?

Comment: You cannot create a parsed `<script>` tag through `innerHTML` (which is what `v-html` would be doing).  [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/691711).

Answer (score 1):

I'd place a v-if directive on the script tag and put the content of it in a variable.

```
<script v-if="script">
  {{script}}
</scrip>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, my answer is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ strWithScriptTag }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: 'Example',

   methods: {
     htmlDecode(input) {
       const e = document.createElement('div')
       e.innerHTML = input
       return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue
     },
   },


  computed: {
     strWithScriptTag() {
       const scriptStr = '&lt;script&gt;https://some.domain.namet&lt;/script&gt;'
       return this.htmlDecode(scriptStr)
     }
   },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can also use lodash's [unescape](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#unescape) instead htmlDecode(input).

Answer (score 0):

I think that by safety vue is escaping your `<script>` automatically and there is no way to avoid this.

Anyway, one thing you can do is `eval(this.property)` on `created()` lifecycle hook.

```
data: {
  script: 'alert("this alert will be shown when the component is created")'
},
created() {
  eval(this.script)
}
```

Use it with caution, as stated in [vue js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html), this may open XSS attacks in your app